# Custom components or open picker programmatically

Tags: maui

I'm building a .Net MAUI Desktop app and I want to create a new component or extend the picker to be able to open it programatically.

1. Open picker programaticly

I would like a component that was an entry where data is displayed and 2 pickers. One will have months and the other week no (1-4) and the behavior will be like this. On click of the entry first picker will open and on selection on the first picker the second will open. I already know about selection and tap events but I need to open the picker from code and I don't know how. I tried with .focus() with no success.

2 Create a new component

Or I saw somewhere that the picker is only a readonly entry with a popup-up. Based on this I tried to create my custom double-picker but I have not managed to position the popup under the entry and to make to not expand it's parent (so my rows in list will not expand)

EDIT: This happens on windows

Answer (score 0):

> I already know about selection and tap events but I need to open the
> picker from code and I don't know how. I tried with .focus() with no
> success.

Currently the behavior of calling `Focus` to open the picker dialogs is broken on Android because of this [PR](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/8913).

And there is a known issue about this problem, you can follow it up here: [Fix (or don't) the behavior of calling "Focus" on Android to open the picker](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8946).

This issue has been moved to the Backlog milestone. This means that it is not going to be worked on for the coming release.

**Update:**

For windows, there is also a feature request of [opening a Picker selection window](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15001) here. This issue has also been added to the backlog.

Thanks for your support and feedback for maui.

Best Regards.

Comment: The project is targeting windows

Comment: For windows, there is also a feature request. You can check my updated answer.